# Can i use the git tag as a version in the build script in Codeship

Tags: build, continuous-integration, codeship

I need to have as a version on AWS the tag I use in GitHub.
Is there an environment variable I can use?

Answer (score 0):

The git tag [would be recognized within the CodeShip Pro environment](https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables) as a `CI_BRANCH` environment variable.